# JavaScript in Chrome Extension returns "cannot read property 'XXX' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been working on a simple Chrome Extension and I have the context menu showing properly, but I can't get the popup to open. I'm trying to get it to differentiate actions based on the selection.

UPDATE

After messing for hours, I think I'm closer, but now I'm getting a "Cannot read property 'linkUrl' of undefined" and I can't figure out where it's coming from.

```
function getEmail(info,tab) {
    chrome.windows.create({
        url: "https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&shva=1&to="+info.linkUrl.substr(7), 
        width:640,
        height:700,
        focused:true,
        type:"popup",
    })
}

function sendEmail(info,tab) {
    chrome.windows.create({
        url: "https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&shva=1&to=" +info.selectionText,
        width:640,
        height:700,
        focused:true,
        type:"popup",
    })
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Send a New Email",
    contexts:["link", "selection"],
    onclick: checkType(),
});

function checkType(info,tab) {
    if (typeof info.linkUrl === $('a[href^="mailto:"]')) {
        console.log("This should print first");
        // getEmail();
    }
    else { 
        console.log("This should print");
        // sendEmail();
    }
}
```

manifest.json

```
{
   "background": {
      "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
   },

   "description": "Creates a context menu option which copies the selected address into a new Gmail compose window.",

   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "New Gmail Window",
   "permissions": [ "tabs", "contextMenus" ],
   "version": "0.1"
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add the `()` after the function calls in the checkType if...else statement. Fixed now.

Comment: Having 2 different versions of code (each with a different set of problems) makes it difficult to helpfully interpret the answers (since one wouldn't know which code version it refers to. Also, posting the manifest might reveal something useful...

Comment: Sorry...still learning. Just updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line: `onclick: checkType(),` attempts to set the **return value** of `checkType()` as the handler for the `onclick` event. Immediately invoking `checkType()` without passing any parameters results in the "Cannot read property 'linkUrl' of undefined" error.

The correct way to register a handler would be:

```
...
onclick: checkType,
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your `checkType` function should be fixed:

```
function checkType(info,tab) {
    if (info.linkUrl === $('a[href^="mailto:"]')) {
        getEmail(info, tab)
    }
    else { 
        sendEmail(info, tab);
    }
};
```

Comment: Tried that, still doesn't want to open the popup window.